# Cute $4$-digit numbers

Tags: number-theory

A $4$-digit number $\overline{abcd}$, with $(a,b,c,d) \ge1$ are called "cute" if satisfy **exactly** $2$ of the $3$ following requirements:

1. $a+b+c+d \le 30$
2. $a+b = c+d$
3. $a+b+c+d \le 10$

> How many cute numbers are there?

So, I divided this problem into $2$ cases here:

1. If 1 and 3 happened, but 2 doesn't

If 3 happened, then 1 must also happen. So, 2 cannot happen, because it doesn't satisfy **exactly** $2$ requirements

1.a. 1 and 3 happened

$a+b+c+d = k$ where $k= 4,5,...,10$ and $1\le a,b,c,d \le 9$
then by stars and bars there are $3C3 + 4C3 + ..+ 9C3  = 210$ ways

1.b, if 2 and 3 happened

$a+b = c+d$ which implies $a+b+c+d=k$ is even, so $k = 4,6,8,10$. Thus, $a+b=c+d=k/2$. And I'm struggling to count this part. Can anybody help?

2. If 1 and 2 happened, but 3 doesn't

Comment: If $3.$ is satisfied , then $1.$ is satisfied as well. The formulation is not quite clear : It could mean exactly two or at least two of the statements must be true.

Comment: yes ofc if 3 is satisfied, then 1 is satisfied as well. But, it is also possible that 2 is satisfied if 3 is satisfied. So we must substract case 2,3 from 1,3 @Peter

Comment: the question said that if it is called cute if it is satisfied exactly 2 of the 3 requirements @Peter

Comment: @legna I don't see the word **exactly** in the posted question.  However, it does seem that the OP (i.e. original poster) is interpreting the question in this manner.  It is unclear what the original specification is, and how faithfully the original specification was posted in the question.

Comment: I edited the question to say **exactly** because the OP said so in the comments.

Comment: a+b=c+d implies a+b+c+d is even, but  a+b+c+d is even does not imply a+b=c+d. So counting how many (a,b,c,d) satisfy a+b+c+d is even is probably not useful.

Comment: "1.a. 1 and 3 happened

...210 ways"  buy you need to *exclude* where $2$ happened.

Answer (score 0):

> A $4$-digit number $\overline{abcd}$, with $(a,b,c,d) \ge1$ are called "cute" if satisfy **exactly** $2$ of the $3$ following requirements:

> Cond-1 : $a+b+c+d \le 30$ 
> Cond-2 : $a+b = c+d$ 
> Cond-3 : $a+b+c+d \le 10$

> How many cute numbers are there?

If Cond-2 and Cond-3 are satisfied, so is Cond-1.  Therefore, the only cute numbers are

- those that satisfy Cond-1,Cond-2 (only)
- or those that satisfy Cond-1,Cond-3 (only).

---

$\underline{\text{Cond-1,Cond-2 only}}$

Let $~S~$ denote the set $~\{6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15\}.$

The solutions for this section will be represented by

$$(a + b) = k = (c + d), ~k \in S. \tag1 $$

Note that solutions represented by (1) above will satisfy Cond-1 and dis-satisfy Cond-3.

For each $~k \leq 10 ~: ~k \in S,~$ you can have $~a~$ run from $~1~$ through $~(k-1),~$ and you can have $~c~$ run from $~1~$ through $~(k-1).$  Therefore, for each value of $~k \leq 10 ~: ~k \in S,~$ there are $~(k-1)^2,~$ possibilities.

For each $~k \geq 11 ~: ~k \in S,~$ you can have $~a~$ run from $~(k - 9)~$ through $~9,~$ and you can have $~c~$ run from $~(k-9)~$ through $~9.~$
Therefore, for each value of $~k \geq 11 ~: ~k \in S,~$ there are $~(19-k)^2,~$ possibilities.

Therefore, the number of cute numbers represented by this section are

$$\sum_{k=6}^{10} (k-1)^2 + \sum_{k=11}^{15} (19-k)^2$$

$$= (5^2 + 6^2 + 7^2 + 8^2 + 9^2) + (8^2 + 7^2 + 6^2 + 5^2 + 4^2) = 445.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Cond-1,Cond-3 only}}$

You need Cond-3 satisfied and Cond-2 dis-satisfied.

To compute the number of ways of satisfying Cond-3, you want the number of solutions to

- $a + b + c + d + X = 10.$
- $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$
- $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{Z_{\leq 9}}.$
- $X \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

The easiest approach here is to temporarily ignore the 3rd bullet point above, and then adjust for it later.

Since [Stars and Bars theory](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/), which is also discussed
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), requires the lower bound to be $~0,~$ I make the standard adjustment of deducting $~1~$ from each of $~a,b,c,d.~$

So, you want the number of solutions to

- $a_1 + b_1 + c_1 + d_1 + X = 10 - 4 = 6.$
- $a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1, X \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

By Stars and Bars theory, the number of solutions is $\displaystyle \binom{6 + [5-1]}{5-1} = \binom{10}{4} = 210.$

Since all $~210~$ solutions require that each of the variables $~a,b,c,d~$ be $~\geq 1,~$ none of these $~210~$ solutions can be violating the constraint that each variable must be $~\leq 9.~$

Therefore,  all of the $~210~$ solutions satisfy Cond-3.

Now, you have to deduct those solutions that satisfy Cond-3, but also satisfy Cond-2.

These solutions will be represented by 
$(a + b) = k = (c + d), ~k \in \{2,3,4,5\}.$

Similar to the previous section, for each $~k,~$ you can have $~a~$ run from $~1~$ through $~(k-1),~$ and you can have $~c~$ run from $~1~$ through $~(k-1).$  Therefore, for each value of $~k,~$ there are $~(k-1)^2,~$ possibilities.

Therefore, the total number of solutions to deduct is

$$\sum_{k=2}^5 (k-1)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^4 k^2 = \frac{4 \times 5 \times 9}{6} = 30.$$

Therefore, the number of cute numbers represented by this section are

$$210 - 30 = 180.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Tally}}$

The number of cute numbers is

$$445 + 180 = 625.$$

Comment: @jepugs : "A $4$-digit number $\overline{abcd}$, with $(a,b,c,d) \ge1$..." : 1506 violates this constraint, because 0 is not permitted.  Please let me know if you agree.  Also, if you (still) think that there is any flaw in my analysis, please also let me know.

Comment: Oh yeah, I misunderstood the question, my mistake. I only commented after writing a python script to count the numbers, so I was just looking for an easy explanation for the discrepancy. My script gives 625 numbers with zero excluded, so I think you may have undercounted still.

Comment: Here's the code. I think it's too simple to have any bugs https://pastebin.com/nih1fn9J , but I've been mistaken before

Comment: Oh, your analysis is all correct. I found the mistake. In counting the cond1, cond2 numbers, you forgot to add 9*9 in the first sum. I think everything else is correct and it matches the results of the python script with that addition.

Comment: @jepugs Nice catch. I agree and I have corrected my answer.  Who knew that $~(10 - 1)~$ wasn't equal to $~8~?$